# Why can't I repeat this user-defined function?

Tags: emacs

For a built-in command like `nextline`,  I can repeat it `n` times by typing `C-u n M-x next-line`. However, for the following user-defined command:

```
(defun smsn-set-priority-public-and-drop-cursor ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (insert (concat "\n                @priority 0.75\n"))
    (kill-line)
    ))
```

if I try `C-u 4 smsn-set-priority-public-and-drop-cursor`, it only happens once. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`C-u n` doesn't specify a number of repetitions, but a numeric prefix argument. How that argument changes the behaviour of a command depends on the definition of that command.

Your command ignores any prefix argument entirely, which is why C-u 4 has no effect whatsoever.

Here's an example command which repeats given a prefix:

```
(defun test (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (while (plusp arg)
    (insert "zonk")
    (setq arg (1- arg))))
```

(`C-u` on its own gives a prefix value of 4, by the way, and has some other neat tricks - see the docstring of `C-u`.)

Comment: See also `C-h f dotimes`.